# Adding spaces based on class for saving text file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a report that can be saved using FileSaver.js. I need to be able to "indent" or add spaces before values in the html before saving it to text file.

Here is HTML example:

```
<div class="s_indent">$_('Endpoint') <span class="endpoint_num"></span></div>
<div class="m_indent">$_('Local Interface'): <span class="local_if"></span></div>
```

- `s_indent` is a short indent, or two spaces
- `m_indent` is a medium indent, or four spaces
- there are also a long indent and extra long indent, with 6 and 8 spaces, respectively.

The HTML is indented via CSS, and it works just fine.

And here is what I have for jQuery:

```
if ($("div").hasClass("s_indent")) {
    $("div.s_indent").appendTo("  ");
}

if ($("div").hasClass("m_indent")) {
    $("div.m_indent").appendTo("    ");
}

final_text = $.trim(final_text.replace(/\n+/g, "\r\n"));

blob = new Blob([final_text], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(blob, "SavedFile.txt");
```

But the file that is saved doesn't have any indentations. Can anyone help?

Comment: when in doubt at least look up the methods you are using. A quick look at what `appendTo` does would tell you it isn't what you want. http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

Comment: instead of a blank space (i.e. " "), try a `&nbsp;` for each space needed.

Comment: Someone had an answer to use `$("div.s_indent").prepend("  ");` or `$("div.s_indent").prepend("&nbsp;&nbsp;");` without the if statements, but that answer was deleted by the owner before I could check it as correct. It worked like a charm, and I don't know who posted that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was someone who posted an answer to solve this. But it was deleted before I could check it as the right answer. And it's not in my history feed, so I cannot look up that person.

He said to remove the `if` statements and use `prepend` as such:

```
    $("div.s_indent").prepend("  ");
    $("div.m_indent").prepend("    ");
```

or:

```
    $("div.s_indent").prepend("&nbsp;&nbsp;");
    $("div.m_indent").prepend("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
```

If you are the person who helped me, please post your answer and I'll re-check yours as correct so you get credit. I only remember your picture. And thank you, anonymous helper!

**Edit:**
User was Six Fingered Man (https://stackoverflow.com/users/4256515/six-fingered-man) Credit for finding him @charlietfl

Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

You need to NOT trim your work.

```
if ($("div").hasClass("s_indent")) {
    $("div.s_indent").appendTo("  ");
}

if ($("div").hasClass("m_indent")) {
    $("div.m_indent").appendTo("    ");
}

final_text = final_text.replace(/\n+/g, "\r\n");

blob = new Blob([final_text], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(blob, "SavedFile.txt");
```